# Returning to the proper page when using AngularJS UI Bootstrap pagination

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, pagination

I'm trying to understand how to go about returning to the proper page of a paginated list of items using AngularJS UI Bootstrap's pagination.

I've got my items properly paginated (12 to a page) and the pagination filter works (page 1 = 1-12, page 2 = 13-24, etc.). I've also created a route to a details template for each item, and that works as well.

On the details page I have a button that goes back to the template at the root of the app ("/"), named "Return to catalog," which is page 1 of the list of items. However, this button goes back to page 1 even for the details of item 24. What I'd like it to do is go to page 2, where item 24 is paginated, and page 3 if the details shown are for any item between 25-36, and so on.

Please advise on how to go about doing something like this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Pagination service` for this case.

For example:

```
app.service('PaginationService', function(){
   var service = {};
   service.currentPageNumber = 1;

   service.setNewPageNumber = function(newPageNumber) {
      service.currentPageNumber = newPageNumber;
   };

   return service;
});

app.controller('CatalogController', function($scope, PaginationService){
   $scope.currentPage = PaginationService.currentPageNumber;
   $scope.totalItems = 0;
   $scope.itemsPerPage = 10;

   $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {
      $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
   };

   $scope.$watch('currentPage', function () {
      PaginationService.setNewPageNumber($scope.currentPage);
   });
});
```

Every time when you change current page number, `PaginationService.setNewPageNumber()` will be called and after return from details page, **controller will be reloaded** and you will have actual page number from the service.

```
$scope.currentPage = PaginationService.currentPageNumber;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Really nice answer

Answer (score 2):

When you route from one page to another you need to store the current page number.
On click of back button when you route back to the current page set the ng-model of the  to previous value.

Storing current page number on page route: call the function in ng-change

```js
$scope.pageChanged = function(pageNo) {
  $rootScope.SavedCurrentPage = pageNo;
};
```

Set the previously stored pageNumber : Important thing to remember here is to set the page number after items are retrieved by the service call. If not , page number would be defaulted to 1

```js
.....getData().then(function(result) {
    if ($rootScope.SavedCurrentPage) {
    $scope.bigCurrentPage = $rootScope.SavedCurrentPage;
  } else {
    $scope.bigCurrentPage = 1;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

mean.js version

```
------------ yo meanjs:angular-service <service-name>------------
    (function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('lista')
    .factory('listaService', listaService);

  listaService.$inject = [/*Example: '$state', '$window' */];

  function listaService(/*Example: $state, $window */) {
    // Pagin service logic
    // ...
    var service = {};
       service.currentPageNumber = 1;
       service.setNewPageNumber = function(newPageNumber) {
         if(newPageNumber>1){
      service.currentPageNumber = newPageNumber;
      }
   };

    // Public API
    return service;
  }
})();
------------------------controller-------------------------------
function buildPager() {
      vm.pagedItems = [];
      vm.itemsPerPage = 10;


       vm.currentPage = listaService.currentPageNumber;
       $scope.$watch('vm.currentPage',function(o,n){
          console.log('current page changed to');
          console.log(o);
         listaService.setNewPageNumber(o);
        });

           vm.figureOutItemsToDisplay();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you for your contribution to this question. You should consider updating your answer, however, to provide details on *what* this code does, *how* it works, and how it solves the problem presented in the question. In the future, when answering or asking questions, avoid just pasting a block of code - actually explain what's going on. See [How to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) from StackOverflow's Help Center.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best way to keep the pagination state is using parameters in the URL. This is also useful for the case in which you want to share an URL with the page number. Otherwise, without the page parameter in the URL, the other user would always land in the first page.

Here is a very complete post about this:

http://www.codelord.net/2015/06/20/simple-pagination-and-url-params-with-ui-router/

So, the important things are:

- Configure the state in your router to receive the **page** parameter

```js
$stateProvider.state('list', {
  url: '/list?page',
  controller: 'ListCtrl',
  controllerAs: 'list',
  templateUrl: 'list.html',
  params: {
    page: {
      value: '1',
      squash: true
    }
  }
});
```

- Handle the **page** parameter when the controller is initializing and update the state on every change of page:

```js
angular
  .module('your.module')
  .controller('ListCtrl', function ($state, $stateParams) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.page = parseInt($stateParams.page || '1'); // page param is a String
    loadStuffForList(); //First time load elements for list

    vm.onPageChange = function () {
      $state.go('.', {'page': '' + vm.page}, {'notify': false}); // notify: false -> prevent the controller from reloading
      loadStuffForList();
    };
    function loadStuffForList () {...};
  });
```

- Regarding your **Back** button, in case you don't want the user to use the browser's **Back** button, I would do something like this:

```html
<a ui-sref="list({page: vm.thisItemPage})">Back</a>
```